# Selecting variables in a dataset according to values in another dataset

Tags: macros, spss

I want to create a subset for a dataset which has around 100 variables and I wish to KEEP only those variables that are present as values of another variable in another dataset. Can someone pleae help me with a SPSS Syntax.

This is what it should look like:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE basedataset.
SAVE OUTFILE ='Newdata.sav'
/KEEP Var1.
```

Var 1 is the variable in the other dataset which contains all the values based on which i want to perform the subsetting.I am not sure if vector should be involved or if there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create a macro containing the list of variables you require, to use in your analysis or in subsetting the data.

First I'll create some sample data to demonstrate on:

```
data list free /v1 to v10 (10f3).
begin data
1,2,3,2,4,7,77,777,66,55
end data.
dataset name basedataset.

data list free/var1 (a4).
begin data
"v3", "v5", "v6", "v9"
end data.
dataset name varnames.
```

Now to create the list:

```
dataset activate varnames.
write out="yourpath\var1 selection.sps" 
    /"VARIABLE ATTRIBUTE VARIABLES= ", var1, " ATTRIBUTE=selectVars('yes')." .
exe.

dataset activate basedataset.
VARIABLE ATTRIBUTE VARIABLES=all  ATTRIBUTE=selectVars('no').
insert file="yourpath\var1 selection.sps".
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!varlist" /ATTRVALUES NAME=selectVars VALUE = yes .
```

The list is now ready and can be called using the macro name `!varlist` in any command, for example:

```
freq !varlist.
```

or

```
SAVE OUTFILE ='Newdata.sav' /KEEP !varlist.
```